# Mock import with enzyme testing on react component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react component that needed to be tested,
I am using jest with enzyme for the testing.

The react component imports other functions to operate that need to be mocked.

I am using it just to mock the import.

```
let mockFeature = {
    feature1 : jest.fn(() => true),
    feature2 :jest.fn(() => true),
 };

beforeEach(() => {
jest.mock('../../viewHelper/featureUtility  ', () => (
    {
        getFeature1 : mockFeature.feature1,
        getFeature2 : mockFeature.feature2
    }
  ));
});
```

When mounting the component the import is not getting mocked.
the expectation is the component will use the mocked implementation instead of real one.

```
    import { mount } from "enzyme";

    const wrapper = mount(
       <MemoryRouter>
          <MyComponent />
       </MemoryRouter>
    );

    test("renders MyComponent", () => {
       expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
    });
```

what is missing here, how to mock the imports in the react testing with enzyme?

Comment: How do you use `getFeature1` and `getFeature2`? Show the code of the `MyComponent`

Answer (score 0):

The mock imports should be out of the beforeEach.
then it works for the current test.

```
jest.mock('../../viewHelper/featureUtility  ', () => (
    {
       getFeature1 : jest.fn(() => true),
       getFeature2 : jest.fn(() => true),
    }
  ));
```